# Ajuste global da largura das tabelas com R e Latex

Tags: r, latex

Estou desenvolvendo um gerador de relatórios com R e LaTeX.

Basicamente, o código R lê os dados e cria gráficos com `ggplot` (salvando em `PNG`) e tabelas em LaTeX com `knitr:kable` (salvando em arquivos `*.tex`).

Depois, eu compilo um arquivo `*.tex` principal que incorpora via `\input` os arquivos `*.tex` com as tabelas.

O caso é que algumas tabelas são mais largas e acabam ficando cortadas na saída em PDF do LaTeX em virtude de que algumas tabelas tem rótulos de colunas um pouco longos.

Existe alguma forma de definir de forma global (não em cada tabela individualmente) uma largura máxima para as tabelas (por exemplo, a largura máxima de `\textwidth` no LaTeX, ou então, uma largura máxima, em cm ou outra unidade, no `kable`), de forma que, caso alguma tabela ultrapasse essa largura máxima, os rótulos das colunas quebrem linha automaticamente?

As tabelas são geradas no R com o seguinte código:

```
# Função que gera as tabelas
app.table.default <- function(data, align = NULL, caption = NULL, format.args = list(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark =",", nsmall = 2), col.names = NULL) {
  tbl <- knitr::kable(data, align=align, caption = caption, format.args = format.args, col.names = col.names, format = "latex")
  tbl <- kable_classic(tbl)
  tbl <- kable_styling(tbl, position = "center", latex_options = c("HOLD_position", "repeat_header"))
  return(tbl)
}
```

Eu pesquisei na ajuda do `kable` e `kableExtras` e sobre o LaTeX e só encontrei soluções onde eu teria que configurar tabela por tabela. Porém, o objetivo é algo no `preamble` do documento base LaTeX ou algo que eu possa configurar na função R.